# Instagram like Refresh Effect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

Hi I'm new to react native so please bear with me I'm trying to implement Instagram like refresh effect in which the content goes down and can see a loader...any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called Pull to Refresh. React Native provides a component that you can plug into ScrollView:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol

There are other libraries available as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But on using this I was just able to get the refresh loader on pull. Could you suggest a way in which the content on my screen would actually move down and that would create a space for a loader animation @Ajay

Comment: How about this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smooth-pull-to-refresh